# Error running Asp.Net Core app on macOS

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Here is the error I get after I start debugging an Asp.Net from Vs Code:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.CreateFileWatcher(String root)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingEnvironmentExtensions.Initialize(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, String applicationName, String contentRootPath, WebHostOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Api.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args)
   at Api.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I don't get this error when I start the app with `dotnet run`.

Running on dotnet v2.0.0

Comment: Could you please provide the solution or a simplified version? Like the csproj, Program.cs and Startup.cs?